# how to automatically update pyserial to latesT?

Tags: python

I have the following code to raise an exception when pyserial version is less than 2.7,how do I programatically run `pip install pyserial --upgrade` to automatically update to latest version and ensure that it installed correctly?

```
   if py_ser_ver < 2.7:
      raise StandardError("PySerial version 2.7 or greater is required. Your version is: " + serial.VERSION)
```

Comment: IMHO What you are doing is the best option. Auot update is not nice if the user has no option of disabling it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use os.system('python -m pip install pyserial --upgrade') or use subprocess

Then once the installation is complete, check using python -m pip list command. This will work even if pip is not in the path.

```
import os
import subprocess

a = os.system('python -m pip install pyserial --upgrade')
if a == 0:
    d = subprocess.Popen('python -m pip list', stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    if 'pyserial' in d[0]:
        print 'success'
```

Comment: This will not work unless pip is in the path (it is not on my system for example) and you are not behind a proxy.

Comment: @RedX modified my answer to Python -m pip, this will work even if pip is not in the path.

Comment: Now python must be in the path.

Comment: @RedX Yes, python should be in the system path. To run python scripts, python will anyways have to be made part of system path. I am making that basic assumption, that users will have have python added to system path.